# Telerik MVC Grid - Custom filtering (client side)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, filter, telerik, grid

I would like to have custom client-side filtering in my Telerik MVC Grid.
This is mean that when user click on the filter icon on a column, instead of the default 
filter of Telerik, I would a custom javascript code to be called.
how do I do this?

thanks

hagai

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but I recently had to do some modifications in the same area. My suggestion is to look at teleik.grid.filtering.js. You will find there all the code that renders the filtering pop-up, so start there with your modification